# How to fix "python installation is corrupted"?

Tags: upgrade, python

I was upgrading from 13.10 to 14.04 (dev for now, stable in a few hours) using `do-release-upgrade` and encountered the following problem:

```
Can not upgrade 

Your python install is corrupted. Please fix the '/usr/bin/python' symlink.
```

I solved the problem after messing around a bit, so I'd like to share my solution here. Hope this could help someone.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

My problem turned out to be solely due to an altered `/usr/bin/python` symlink as suggested in the error message. I was using `update-alternatives` with `/usr/bin/python` so it was pointing to `/etc/alternatives/python`. Turned out that `do-release-upgrade` is really strict with this symlink and merely selecting python2.7 with `update-alternatives` isn't enough, so I ended up forcing it to its original state:

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
```

And that solved the problem.

If this doesn't work for you, then I guess you have a genuinely corrupted python install. I'd suggest

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python
```

Comment: @BenjaminKohl Glad it helped :)

Comment: Wasn't `/etc/alternatives/python` symlinked to `/usr/bin/python2.7`? did something else has higher priority?

Comment: I am afraid you are getting it backwards....`/usr/bin/python2.7` is the actual binary, it should never be the symlink, the symlink is the `/etc/alternatives/python`..do you mind checking it again?

Comment: @heemayl Sorry, misread your comment + typo on my part. `/usr/bin/python` is a symlink to `/etc/alternatives/python` (of course `/usr/bin/python2.7` is the binary, but that's not the problem here).

Comment: And yes, `/etc/alternatives/python` is then symlinked to whatever you selected (not necessarily `/usr/bin/python2.7` — why would you even need `update-alternatives` in that case?), but the point is symlinking is not allowed for `/usr/bin/python` when you `do-release-upgrade`.

Comment: In my case this was not enough: I also had to tweak /usr/share/python/debian_defaults so that it matches the version /usr/bin/python points to.

Comment: In my case I wasn't using alternatives ("update-alternatives --get-selections" didn't show python). Python was also working happily with apparently good links for /usr/bin/python and python2. Simply remaking the link for /usr/bin/python was enough to allow the update to work. FWIW. My Ubuntu is on a VMware VM.

Answer (score 21):

this one is correct:

```
sudo update-alternatives --remove-all python
sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
```

Comment: This is absolutely correct. It would not work for me until I also first removed all existing using the `update-alternatives --remove-all python`

Answer (score 6):

In Ubuntu 18.10 there is still the same issue.

The /usr/bin/python is linked to an older version. Even later than 2.7 are available but this super-smart process is asking (in 18.10!) for P 2.7. So I gave it and it was accepted.

This solved it for me:

1) delete /usr/bin/python doing `sudo rm  /usr/bin/python`

2) Create a new link `sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python`

In 18.10 I could NOT use `sudo update-alternatives --remove-all python`  or `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python` .

Works for me. Hope it helps you,  too.

Comment: `ls -sf` overrides the target so 1) is pointless, and 2) is exactly what my answer told you to do. What a waste...

Comment: Dont rant: Your quote is wrong and I told the opposite of what you tell about "... --reinstall python". Yes, my experience with 18.10 is different than yours and I explain this. No need at all for brazen comments.

Comment: Saw "If this doesn't work for you, then I guess you have a genuinely corrupted python install."?

Comment: Basically, the lesson is: you read the surroundings and learn why, not just cherrypick whatever code blocks there are, paste them into your terminal (dangerous), and see what sticks. By the way, your `sudo rm` is still pointless.

Comment: Your comments are welcome.

Comment: True, it works on 18.10. Thanks.

Comment: Step 2 fixes the issue. Very bizarre given the default is Python3 now!

Answer (score 5):

If you run into this regarding `/usr/bin/python3` then:

```
sudo update-alternatives --remove-all python3
sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin/python3
```

Make sure to symlink `python3.6` and not `3.7`. At least that was required when upgrading `Ubuntu 18.10` to `19.04`.

Comment: This was the solution for me since I manually forced the installation of python3 with external PPA

Answer (score 4):

For **Ubuntu 19.04** the default python version is 3.7 . I got same error while upgrading to Ubuntu 19.10, and, the following helped:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3
sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python3.7 /usr/bin/python3
```

In case you have very serious problems with your python package, the only way left is to force remove it, and then reinstall it:

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq --force-depends python3
sudo apt-get -f install
```