# Can not upgrade -- Python install corrupted

Tags: upgrade, symbolic-link

Finally trying to upgrade from 16.04 LTS to 17.04 (then to 17.10), but keep running into `"Can not updrade"   "Your python install is corrupted. Pleas fix the '/usr/bin/python' symlink`.

I have already changed the symlink from pointing to `/etc/alternatives/python`, to pointing to `/usr/bin/python3.5`, then later to pointing to `/usr/bin/python2.7`, both times, forcing a reinstall of python along the way.

I keep getting the "Can not upgrade" message box.  It is entirely possible there may be another issue, because along the way, it mentions `Failed to download repository information` and to check the Internet connection.  Then, when I click OK, the software updater repairs itself to inform me that my computer is up to date, but there is a new version...

Since I can get to this forum, I believe that my connection to the Internet is OK, unless the U.S Server is down at the moment.

Any thoughts welcomed...

readlink -e /usr/bin/python 
   /home/mitch/anaconda2/bin/python2.7

python --version Python 2.7.14
  Anaconda custom (64-bit)

apt-cache policy python-minimal python-minimal
  Installed: 2.7.11-1 Candidate: 2.7.11-1 Version table: *** 2.7.11-1 500 500

Comment: Do you confirm you already tried this? https://askubuntu.com/a/448927/271 ...and this? https://askubuntu.com/a/762433/271

Comment: Debugging upgrades is a PITA, and, due to the changes to Ubuntu, I would back up your data and do a fresh install of 17.10. In theory , if you do not format / or /home if separate, your data will be preserved, but back up in case. oh, and read the 17.10 release notes and test on a live usb.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `readlink -e /usr/bin/python`, `/usr/bin/python --version` and `apt-cache policy python-minimal`? Thanks.

Comment: I did not try the second suggestion (didn't find it during a search).  I will try that one and let you know.  as far as the the output of a readlink...

mitch@mitch-fortem:~$ readlink -e /usr/bin/python
/home/mitch/anaconda2/bin/python2.7

mitch@mitch-fortem:~$ python --version
Python 2.7.14 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)

mitch@mitch-fortem:~$ apt-cache policy python-minimal
python-minimal:
  Installed: 2.7.11-1
  Candidate: 2.7.11-1
  Version table:
 *** 2.7.11-1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Comment: OK, I tried the "update-alternatives --remove-all python".  

Now,  update-manager still comes back with "Failed to download repository information".  clicking "OK" still brings up a new dialog box "The software on this computer is up to date."  However, Ubuntu...  now available..." following through... still get the same "Can not upgrade"...  symlink.       I repeated this twice, just to make sure.