# "Your python3 install is corrupted"

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, python3, do-release-upgrade

I want to upgrade from Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS to 18.04, so ran `sudo do-release-upgrade`.
After downloading and extracting `bionic.tar.gz` I get:

```
Can not upgrade 

Your python3 install is corrupted. Please fix the '/usr/bin/python3'
symlink.
```

I saw [How to fix "python installation is corrupted"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/448926/how-to-fix-python-installation-is-corrupted) and so I did `sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin/python3` thinking that it would be a similar problem. But that didn't work (still same error message).

I have a few python versions:

```
$ ls /usr/lib | grep python
python2.7
python3
python3.5
python3.6

$ update-alternatives --display python3
python3 - auto mode
  link best version is /usr/bin/python3.6
  link currently points to /usr/bin/python3.6
  link python3 is /usr/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3.5 - priority 1
/usr/bin/python3.6 - priority 2
```

How do I fix `python3`?

Comment: And what about reinstallation (as mentioned in accepted answer)?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You need to use the default Python 3 version for 16.04. That's [3.5](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/python3), not 3.6. So run:

```sh
sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python3.5 /usr/bin/python3
```

If that doesn't work, try reinstalling the `python3` package.

```sh
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3
```

By the way, `update-alternatives --display python3` should give you `update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for python3`. Different versions of Python are not alternatives in Ubuntu.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work. 
https://kempelen.dai.fmph.uniba.sk/python_headache.png
The system is up to date, and I have reinstalled the python and python3 packages, still the same. It is unique to this machine, other similar machine upgraded fine.

Comment: @palo I'm thinking that the reinstall command I mentioned previously might not actually reinstall everything. Try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3 python3-minimal python3.5 python3.5-minimal`.

Comment: thank you for a quick response. I tried as you suggested, but the same message "Your python3 install is corrupted. Please fix the '/usr/bin/python3' symlink" is still in the way. Uninstalling python3 is not much an option as it blows away too many dependent packages. If you have any idea what to investigate, I will do that.

Comment: It could have something to do with software installed by my colleagues on this machine in some local folders. I see there is linux embedded for rpi, miniconda3 that includes python3.6, and /usr/local/python2.7. Still which python reports /usr/bin/python, but pip goes from /usr/local/bin/pip. Even after changing /etc/environment placing /usr/local/... at the very end of the PATH, still the same message. I noticed that pyversions -d reports: "/usr/bin/python does not match the python default version. It must be reset to point to python2.7". So I replaced the link /usr/bin/python to point...

Comment: ...directly to /usr/bin/python2.7 instead of /etc/alternatives/python, and suddenly pyversions -d was happy, and do-release-upgrade did not complain about python and started the upgrade process as expected! So the problem was probably only this indirect double-linked path from python to python2.7 through /etc/alternatives.

Comment: @Palo Ah so you found the same solution as [the top-voted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1108039/301745)

Comment: Well, I found that answer very confusing. First, I have no idea what "Pop!_OS 18.04" is, and I was upgrading from LTS 16.04 to 18.04, not from 18.04 to 18.10, and also, I have no idea what possible consequences could `sudo update-alternatives --remove-all python` have, so I did not bother doing that and rather tried a small step that I can easily undo. But good that you point that. :) Thanks.

Comment: And it would be nice to fix that upgrade script eventually to 1) not report misinformation about python3 link, and 2) detect this automatically not to stay in the way of poor users who like to bother with python about as much as waking up after 30 minutes long night. I mean, if somebody invents a language where the amount of white-space changes semantics, that guy must have never really used a computer.

Comment: After breaking my system with the previous answer (@J. B. Rainsberger), this actually worked, I had multiple versions of python installed into my Ubuntu-18.04 (3.4, 3.6, 3.10 e.t.c.), after using `ls -l /usr/bin/python*` to find my versions with symbolic links lost, I have used `sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin/python3`, and reinstalled `python3` that fixed the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 80):

I just ran into this problem on Pop!_OS 18.04, trying to upgrade to 18.10, and it turns out that the problem lay in the symlink for `/usr/bin/python` and not for `/usr/bin/python3`. I had had `/usr/bin/python3.6` configured as an alternative for `python` (not `python3`), and when I changed this, then I could run `do-release-upgrade` as expected.

I wish the error message pointed to `python` and not `python3`.

---

Before, with the problem:

```
$ update-alternatives --display python
python - manual mode
  link best version is /usr/bin/python3.6
  link currently points to /usr/bin/python2.7
  link python is /usr/bin/python
/usr/bin/python2.7 - priority 1
/usr/bin/python3.6 - priority 2
```

---

I fixed it this way:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --remove-all python
$ sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
```

---

Also see [this comment below](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1104052/your-python3-install-is-corrupted/1108039?noredirect=1#comment1910548_1108039) which describes a more precise solution that also better explains what is going on and how to fix it.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that the solution works, this should be accepted answer.

Comment: Opting for `update-alternatives --remove-all python` was definitely an unnecessary overkill: All you needed to do was using `update-alternatives --config python` to have `python` point to the latest `python2.*` (e.g. `python2.7`), then use `update-alternatives --config python3` to have `python3` point to **specifically** `python3.6` — which is the default Python 3 version for 18.04.

Comment: If you need to upgrade to python 3.7 in Ubuntu 18.04, don't do it systemwide — or you're bound to end up having nasty little problems _systemwide_ with essential tools like `gnome-terminal`, `update-manager`, etc. Rather use virtual environments (documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) and [here](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html))

Comment: @Kiri There are ways to install other versions of Python without replacing the system one(s). For example [using the deadsnakes PPA](https://askubuntu.com/a/101634/301745).

Comment: @KiriSakow: `update-alternatives --config python3` does not work as `python3` is not a valid "link group" in the alternatives system.

Comment: This is what worked for me. I had both python and python3 poiting to python3.6. I had to point /usr/bin/python back to python2.6

Comment: my /usr/bin/python was pointing to python 3.7 instead of 2.7, and my /usr/bin/python3 was also pointing to 3.7. getting /usr/bin/python pointed to 2.7 cleared my python3 corrupt error

Comment: I also solved this by `sudo ln -s python2.7 python; sudo ln -s python3.5 python3`. It looks like do-release-upgrade doesn't recognize alternatives settings. python and python3 should directly point to python2.7 and python3.5 (for ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: WARNING: Don't do `sudo update-alternatives --remove-all python`, it will break your python2 and maybe even python3. It's overkill.

Comment: @ioaniatr I think that's intentional actually. But the `sudo ln` after is meant to fix it.

Answer (score 24):

None of the answers here seem to explain how you can get to the solution yourself, so I took on a journey, in my case inspecting `do-release-upgrade` in KDE Neon on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

First, I ran it with [`tracefile -w`](https://gitlab.com/ole.tange/tangetools/blob/master/tracefile/tracefile) and discovered that the actual release-upgrade-scripts were downloaded into a `/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-xxxxxxxx` directory.

Using `grep` in that directory, I found the error message in `DistUpgradeController.py`:

```
❯ grep --line-number --recursive --binary-files=without-match "python3 install is corrupted"
DistUpgradeController.py:426:                             _("Your python3 install is corrupted. "
```

So I inspected the surrounding code, which used the function `_pythonSymlinkCheck`, jumped to that and discovered the root of the problem:
The script expected the symlink `/usr/bin/python3` to resolve to exactly `/usr/bin/<debian_default_python>`:

```
binaries_and_dirnames = [("python3", "python3")]
for binary, dirname in binaries_and_dirnames:
    debian_defaults = '/usr/share/%s/debian_defaults' % dirname
    if os.path.exists(debian_defaults):
        config = SafeConfigParser()
        with open(debian_defaults) as f:
            config.readfp(f)
        try:
            expected_default = config.get('DEFAULT', 'default-version')
        except NoOptionError:
            logging.debug("no default version for %s found in '%s'" %
                          (binary, config))
            return False
        try:
            fs_default_version = os.readlink('/usr/bin/%s' % binary)
        except OSError as e:
            logging.error("os.readlink failed (%s)" % e)
            return False
        if not fs_default_version in (expected_default, os.path.join('/usr/bin', expected_default)):
```

As visible from the script, `<debian_default_python>` is the `default-version` key in the `DEFAULT` section from `/usr/share/python3/debian_defaults`:

```
❯ cat /usr/share/python3/debian_defaults
[DEFAULT]
# the default python3 version
default-version = python3.6
```

My link did point to `/usr/bin/python3.6`, but via an extra indirection from `update-alternatives`, which the script doesn't resolve:

```py
❯ python
Python 3.6.9 (default, Jul 17 2020, 12:50:27)
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.readlink("/usr/bin/python3")
'/etc/alternatives/python3'
>>> os.readlink("/etc/alternatives/python3")
'/usr/bin/python3.6'
```

So in the end I also resorted to the nuclear option, but now with full knowledge of what was going on :)

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin/python3
```

Comment: My goodness, error message could have been better. Thousands of hours must have been wasted for all. It is not a problem of corruption, it is differnet version. People would only think of reinstalling by that word.

Comment: It looks like this part of [the script](https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/tree/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py) has been fixed now cause it uses [`os.path.realpath()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.realpath), which resolves a symbolic link recursively, unlike [`os.readlink()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.readlink), which only resolves the first link in a chain.

Answer (score 16):

I observed this error message on **Windows 10 1903 running WSL Ubuntu** when I wanted to upgrade from **16.04 LTS** to **18.04 LTS**.

After `do-release-upgrade` had failed, I switched `python` alternatives to every choice offered by `update-alternatives --config python` and ran the upgrade command again. That did not help.

Then I checked the log file `/var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log` which contained the lines

```
2019-09-02 20:58:08,686 DEBUG _pythonSymlinkCheck run
2019-09-02 20:58:08,687 DEBUG python symlink points to: '/etc/alternatives/python', but expected is 'python2.7' or
'/usr/bin/python2.7'
2019-09-02 20:58:08,688 ERROR pythonSymlinkCheck() failed, aborting
```

So although the error message mentions **python3**, the issue is about **python2**.

The upgrade script checks for `/usr/bin/python` linking to `/usr/bin/python2`, see the source code of `DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py` here: [ubuntu launchpad](https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/tree/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py?h=ubuntu/bionic-updates#n361)

So one solution is to completely remove python from the alternative system and add the link manually, as described in the most popular answer.

If you don't want to remove python from the alternative system, just change the link only for the time during the upgrade process:

```
# rm /usr/bin/python 
# ln -sf /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
# do-release-upgrade
```

This worked for me.

During the upgrade process, the link is automatically repaired. So when the upgrade is finished, it points to the python entry in the alternatives directory:

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 24 Sep  2 22:01 /usr/bin/python -> /etc/alternatives/python
```

Edit: for thorough information, the issue might also appear if you upgrade from 18.04 LTS to 19.04 and the anwser applies to this situation, too.

Comment: Note: This answer also applies to an upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to 19.04. I tried it myself after the update to 18.04 had finished successfully.

Comment: This worked for me. The symlinks in /usr/bin/python and /usr/bin/python3 must be absolute:

```tail /var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log```   revealed     ```2021-10-07 14:34:42,156 DEBUG python symlink points to: './python2.7', but 
expected is 'python2.7' or '/usr/bin/python2.7'```. You need all three python links intact and absolute: /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/python3.

Answer (score 6):

Basically the solution to this problem consists of making `/usr/bin/python` point to the right version of Python your Ubuntu release expects (for instance, in 16.04 was Python2.7 and in 18.04 was Python3.6).

If you have several versions of Python installed in your system, you might be using `update-alternatives` to manage them. It doesn't matter much your default alternative for Python is the right version your system expects (3.6 in Ubuntu 18.04), it won't work.

The reason why this doesn't work is that, when using `update-alternatives`, `/usr/bin/python3` points to `/etc/alternatives/python3`, and it seems that's not exactly the same as making `/usr/bin/python3` point to `/usr/bin/python3.6`.

That's why the solution to this problem often consists of stop managing your Python3 versions with `update-alternatives` and make `/usr/bin/python3` point to the right version of Python3 your system expects.

Comment: `/usr/bin/python` doesn't exist on a clean install of 18.04, but it does if you do an upgrade instead of a clean install or install the `python` package, in which case it should be Python 2.7, not 3.6. See [PEP 394](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/).

Comment: To be clear, different versions of Python are not alternatives on Ubuntu and should not be managed with `update-alternatives`. This is because the OS relies on a certain version being installed.

Comment: It would be nice if the error message reported what the actual error is - `python` not being set correctly instead of `python3` ...

Answer (score 2):

The following commands should work:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2.7 1
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.5 2
sudo rm /usr/bin/python
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Answer (score 2):

I just tried upgrading to jammy (22.04) and hit the same error. The error comes down to an incorrect symlink check in the upgrader package. I've submitted a bug report with a fix in [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1953135).

What you can do to work around the problem is have your `python3` link *directly* to the final executable (without the detour via `/etc/alternatives/python3`):

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3.9 /usr/bin/python3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fix when I tried to upgrade my xenial 16.04 box to 18.04

```
mkdir /usr/share/python2/
cp /usr/share/python/debian_defaults /usr/share/python2/debian_defaults
cd /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/python.27
```

otherwise, the ubuntu-release-upgrader will complain with messages like

```
/usr/lib/python3$ sudo do-release-upgrade 
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [819 B]                                                                                                                                                                               
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,245 kB]                                                                                                                                                                                      
Fetched 1,245 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                                                                                                                     
authenticate 'bionic.tar.gz' against 'bionic.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'bionic.tar.gz'

Reading cache

Checking package manager

Can not upgrade 

Your python3 install is corrupted. Please fix the '/usr/bin/python3' 
symlink.
```

The major log file is located at

```
/var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log
```

and there the release updater complained. Also, the other file you may want to check out is actually in /tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader/*

```
less /tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader/*/DistUpgradeController.py
```