# How to fix: ubuntu 19.04 cannot upgrade to 19.10 error "Your python3 install is corrupted. Please fix the '/usr/bin/python3'"

Tags: upgrade, python, 19.04, python3

I tried to run the distribution upgrade on Ubuntu 19.04:
`sudo do-release-upgrade`

I got the error:

```
Can not upgrade`

Your python3 install is corrupted. Please fix the '/usr/bin/python3' 
symlink.
```

Checking the symlinks:

```
ll /usr/bin/pyt*`
/usr/bin/python -> /usr/bin/python3*
/usr/bin/python2 -> python2.7*
/usr/bin/python2.7*
/usr/bin/python3 -> /usr/bin/python3.7*
/usr/bin/python3.7*
/usr/bin/python3.7m*
/usr/bin/python3m -> python3.7m*
```

Comment: You can accept your own answer in order to mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not with the `/usr/bin/python3` symlink, but with `/usr/bin/python`

To correct, for 19.04, I ran

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
```

I found the solution here: ["Your python3 install is corrupted"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1104052/your-python3-install-is-corrupted)
looking at the answer from J. B. Rainsberger