# Unable to do-release-upgrade because which python point to env/bin/python

Tags: python, do-release-upgrade

I would like to upgrade my Ubuntu to 20.04.3 LTS from 18.04.6 LTS but I have an error when running `do-release-upgrade` :

```
Cannot upgrade 

Your python3 install is corrupted. Please fix the '/usr/bin/python3' 
symlink.
```

I noticed that python point to my virtual environement even when it's not activated.

```
user@abc-lenovo-ideapad-710s-13isk$ which python
/home/user/python/env/bin/python
```

My question is how can I make python points to `/usr/bin/python3.9` ?

This is what I have tried :

```
sudo update-alternatives  --set python /usr/bin/python3.9     
update-alternatives: error: alternative /usr/bin/python3.9 for python not registered; not setting
```

This command works with python3 but unfortunnatly it doesn't change and `which python` still points to the `/home/bragar/python/env/bin/python`

This is all the python binaries:

```
user@abc-lenovo-ideapad-710s-13isk:~$ ls /usr/bin/python*
/usr/bin/python     /usr/bin/python2.7-config  /usr/bin/python3.6         /usr/bin/python3.6m-config  /usr/bin/python3.9         /usr/bin/python3-jsonschema  /usr/bin/python-config
/usr/bin/python2    /usr/bin/python2-config    /usr/bin/python3.6-config  /usr/bin/python3.7          /usr/bin/python3.9-config  /usr/bin/python3m
/usr/bin/python2.7  /usr/bin/python3           /usr/bin/python3.6m        /usr/bin/python3.7m         /usr/bin/python3-config    /usr/bin/python3m-config
```

Comment: I'd tried that once. My advice: don't do it. Save your data and install it freshly...

Comment: Do you suggest to reinstall from scratch ? but why ?

Comment: Because your python installation is corrupted

Comment: Because Ubuntu is not a rolling release. Try an arch or manjaro distro iif you want this. It took me several  years of Ubuntu Linux before I was ready for it. That's the reason why I'm active in this forum. Ubuntu is designed to be refreshed every 4 years - this is not Windows with a legacy of 40 years.

Comment: I would like to solve my python installation no reinstall from scratch

Comment: Won't work & good luck. `do-release-upgrade`won't handle your "special" python config.

Comment: Reinstallation costs hours of post-install procedures. @kanehekili Ubuntu is not Windows, Ubuntu can be repaired from any "broken" state using standard tools and knowledge. I'm running do-release-upgrade for years, have a system upgraded from 6.06 LTS to latest 21.10.

Comment: Not sure if this is working only idea from me `sudo dpkg-reconfigure python3`

Comment: Please show the output of `echo $PATH`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove your local python from PATH environment variable and run upgrade process by using the following commands:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
sudo -E apt-get update
sudo -E apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo -E do-release-upgrade
```

Comment: Thanks, but it asks `Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.`. What should I do ?

Comment: See update above.

Comment: Now the command `which python` points to `/usr/bin/python` but unfortunnatly the `do-release-upgrade` still complains. `Your python3 install is corrupted. Please fix the '/usr/bin/python3' symlink`

Comment: With `python3` pointing to `/usr/bin/python3.9`. Not sure why is the problem

Comment: Sure, output is `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`

Comment: Oh, I finally manage to do it by following this answer, with complete reinstallation of Python 3.7 as suggested in the comment section by @wjandrea https://askubuntu.com/a/1104066/416440