How can i upgrade Ubuntu?
I am trying to upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04
During update, I get an error

Your python3 install is corrupted. Please fix the ’/usr/bin/python3’
symlink.

I know changing the symlink to the correct version should help. But I cannot Find info as to which version of Python does Ubuntu 22.04 ship with.
If anyone can tell that will be great .

you do not need to care ... upgrading Ubuntu to next release takes care of upgrading python to the proper version ... just get your current box squared away then upgrade ... details on your issue see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1104052/your-python3-install-is-corrupted

In 22.04 it should be /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.10, and in 20.04 - /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.8

I found the default version of python3 in Ubuntu 22.04 by running the python3 command. It is currently Python 3.10.12 which corresponds to the python3.10 package.
